# make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop. make: *** [../common/common.mk:94: ../lib/install/lib/libxdp.a] Error 2

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, makefile, xdp-pdf

I am working on xdp tutorial using the documentation in guthub repository
while on first step in basic01 after installing all the dependencies i got this error when I run command "make" as guided in the README.org

This is my MakeFile

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR BSD-2-Clause)

XDP_TARGETS := xdp_pass_kern  
USER_TARGETS := xdp_pass_user

LLC ?= llc
CLANG ?= clang
CC := gcc

COMMON_DIR = ../common
COMMON_OBJS += $(COMMON_DIR)/common_user_bpf_xdp.o

include $(COMMON_DIR)/common.mk
```

This is my xdp_pass_kern.c which expected to be converted into xdp_pass_kern.o
after running command `make`

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

SEC("xdp")
int  xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

This is my common.mk file

```
# Common Makefile parts for BPF-building with libbpf
# --------------------------------------------------
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR BSD-2-Clause)
#
# This file should be included from your Makefile like:
#  COMMON_DIR = ../common
#  include $(COMMON_DIR)/common.mk
#
# It is expected that you define the variables:
#  XDP_TARGETS and USER_TARGETS
# as a space-separated list
#
LLC ?= llc
CLANG ?= clang
CC ?= gcc

XDP_C = ${XDP_TARGETS:=.c}
XDP_OBJ = ${XDP_C:.c=.o}
USER_C := ${USER_TARGETS:=.c}
USER_OBJ := ${USER_C:.c=.o}

# Expect this is defined by including Makefile, but define if not
COMMON_DIR ?= ../common
LIB_DIR ?= ../lib

COPY_LOADER ?=
LOADER_DIR ?= $(LIB_DIR)/xdp-tools/xdp-loader
STATS_DIR ?= $(COMMON_DIR)/../basic-solutions

COMMON_OBJS += $(COMMON_DIR)/common_params.o
include $(LIB_DIR)/defines.mk

# Create expansions for dependencies
COMMON_H := ${COMMON_OBJS:.o=.h}

EXTRA_DEPS +=

# BPF-prog kern and userspace shares struct via header file:
KERN_USER_H ?= $(wildcard common_kern_user.h)

CFLAGS += -I$(LIB_DIR)/install/include $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
BPF_CFLAGS += -I$(LIB_DIR)/install/include $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIB_DIR)/install/lib

BPF_HEADERS := $(wildcard $(HEADER_DIR)/*/*.h) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE_DIR)/*/*.h)

all: llvm-check $(USER_TARGETS) $(XDP_OBJ) $(COPY_LOADER) $(COPY_STATS)

.PHONY: clean $(CLANG) $(LLC)

clean:
    $(Q)rm -f $(USER_TARGETS) $(XDP_OBJ) $(USER_OBJ) $(COPY_LOADER) $(COPY_STATS) *.ll

ifdef COPY_LOADER
$(LOADER_DIR)/$(COPY_LOADER):
    $(Q)make -C $(LOADER_DIR)

$(COPY_LOADER): $(LOADER_DIR)/$(COPY_LOADER)
    $(QUIET_COPY)cp $(LOADER_DIR)/$(COPY_LOADER) $(COPY_LOADER)
endif

ifdef COPY_STATS
$(STATS_DIR)/$(COPY_STATS): $(STATS_DIR)/${COPY_STATS:=.c} $(COMMON_H)
    $(Q)make -C $(STATS_DIR) $(COPY_STATS)

$(COPY_STATS):  $(STATS_DIR)/$(COPY_STATS)
    $(QUIET_COPY)cp $(STATS_DIR)/$(COPY_STATS) $(COPY_STATS)
# Needing xdp_stats imply depending on header files:
EXTRA_DEPS += $(COMMON_DIR)/xdp_stats_kern.h $(COMMON_DIR)/xdp_stats_kern_user.h
endif

# For build dependency on this file, if it gets updated
COMMON_MK = $(COMMON_DIR)/common.mk

llvm-check: $(CLANG) $(LLC)
    @for TOOL in $^ ; do \
        if [ ! $$(command -v $${TOOL} 2>/dev/null) ]; then \
            echo "*** ERROR: Cannot find tool $${TOOL}" ;\
            exit 1; \
        else true; fi; \
    done

$(OBJECT_LIBBPF):
    @if [ ! -d $(LIBBPF_DIR) ]; then \
        echo "Error: Need libbpf submodule" $(LIBBPF_DIR); \
        echo "May need to run git submodule update --init"; \
        exit 1; \
    else \
        cd $(LIBBPF_DIR) && $(MAKE) all OBJDIR=.; \
        mkdir -p build; $(MAKE) install_headers DESTDIR=build OBJDIR=.; \
    fi

$(OBJECT_LIBXDP):
    @if [ ! -d $(LIBXDP_DIR) ]; then \
        echo "Error: Need libxdp submodule" $(LIBXDP_DIR); \
        echo "May need to run git submodule update --init"; \
        exit 1; \
    else \
        cd $(LIBXDP_DIR) && $(MAKE) all OBJDIR=.; \
    fi

# Create dependency: detect if C-file change and touch H-file, to trigger
# target $(COMMON_OBJS)
$(COMMON_H): %.h: %.c
    touch $@

# Detect if any of common obj changed and create dependency on .h-files
$(COMMON_OBJS): %.o: %.h
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -C $(COMMON_DIR)

$(USER_TARGETS): %: %.c  $(OBJECT_LIBBPF) $(OBJECT_LIBXDP) Makefile $(COMMON_MK) $(COMMON_OBJS) $(KERN_USER_H) $(EXTRA_DEPS)
    $(QUIET_CC)$(CC) -Wall $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(COMMON_OBJS) $(LIB_OBJS) \
     $< $(LDLIBS)

$(XDP_OBJ): %.o: %.c  Makefile $(COMMON_MK) $(KERN_USER_H) $(EXTRA_DEPS) $(OBJECT_LIBBPF)
    $(QUIET_CLANG)$(CLANG) -S \
        -target bpf \
        -D __BPF_TRACING__ \
        $(BPF_CFLAGS) \
        -Wall \
        -Wno-unused-value \
        -Wno-pointer-sign \
        -Wno-compare-distinct-pointer-types \
        -Werror \
        -O2 -emit-llvm -c -g -o ${@:.o=.ll} $<
    $(QUIET_LLC)$(LLC) -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o $@ ${@:.o=.ll}
```

I am expecting it to create xdp_pass_kern.c into xdp_pass_kern.o for my further steps

You can also check the git repository I am following
https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/basic01-xdp-pass

Please help me achieve this

Comment: As stated in the error message the real problem probably lies in the file `../common/common.mk`.  You need to show us that.

Comment: [edit] your question to show `../common/common.mk`.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: I think we need to see more of `make`'s output.  At least the last build command, if any, echoed to the output, and everything following.  If no build commands are echoed at all, then probably the whole output (which I'm supposing won't be very long in that case).

Comment: Is it indeed `MakeFile` with capital `F`?

Comment: The error message is consistent with there not being a target `all:` anywhere in your make rules. Now since `common.mk` unconditionally defines such a target, something is wrong. If that `include $(COMMON_DIR)/common.mk` is working, it must be picking up some other `common.mk`, and not the one shown here.  Or else if the right file is being included, you are not running that makefile which includes it, but some other one somehow.

Comment: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/basic01-xdp-pass
You can check the guide i am following.
Please help I have to submit this project asap.

Comment: The use of `$(Q)` seems misdirected; there is already `make -s` if you want it to run silently.

Comment: @JohnBollinger 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'install_headers'.  Stop.
make: *** [../common/common.mk:84: ../lib/install/lib/libbpf.a] Error 2

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do when trying to debug a makefile, is remove all the `@` prefixes so you can see the actual commands being invoked.  Else it's like trying to debug a program while sending all its output to `/dev/null`.

If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU Make you can add the `--trace` option to the command line and make will print all the commands without you having to edit the makefile and remove the `@` chars.

Also, when posting code with an error message at a given line number please make an effort to show us which line that is.  We don't want to have to count the lines ourselves.

My suspicion is the problem is here:

```
    cd $(LIBBPF_DIR) && $(MAKE) all OBJDIR=.; \
```

I expect it's this sub-make which is throwing the error.  Most likely the contents of the `LIBBPF_DIR` directory (that variable is not being set anywhere that you've shown us so we have no idea what's in it) do not include a `Makefile` so there's no `all` rule defined there.

Maybe you're supposed to run `./configure` or similar there to create the makefile.

Comment: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/basic01-xdp-pass

This is the xdp project i am working on

Comment: Sorry but I don't have the time or energy to go debugging other peoples' projects.  If you want help (from me) you'll have to invest the energy into understanding the situation well enough to provide important details here on SO and take the comments given and work with them.